# Reading data from a private API

Tags: php, api

I found this private API for a game I have been playing which would allow me to create a pretty cool profile search website, however the API is structured a bit weird and I am not entirely sure how to call elements from this type of API.

```
{
"status": "success",
"id": "some_id_here",
"denormalized": {
    "some_url_here": {
        "data": {
            "created": "2019-01-10T04:19:21Z",
            "registered": 1547093961,
            "gender": "f",
            "display_name": "",
            "age": 23,
            "country": "US",
            "state": "NY",
        },  
    },
}
```

Above is the type of API that the platform has, it looks like as I scroll through it that it's just a private API for front end elements (cosmetic stuff) etc, I've excluded anything that could be personal.

Any way someone can help me figure out how to call from here? The portion which contains `some_url_here` is different for every unique user, I've done the following.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "some_website_url",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($response, true); //because of true, it's in an array
print '<pre>';
print_r($response);
print '</pre>';
```

but with that being said I can't get past the

```
[denormalized] => Array
        (
            [url-here] => Array
                (
                    [data] =>
```

portion to return the contents that come after `[data]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the key / value pairs of *denormalized* using `foreach`. For example

```php
foreach ($response['denormalized'] as $url => $value) {
    $data = $value['data'];

    $created = $data['created'];
    $registered = $data['registered'];
    // and so on
}
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/AtXCQ

Comment: Thank you so much! Holy cow! It's always the simple solutions, glad I learned something today :D